# ArcGIS Server 10 Manager remote viewing is seemingly broken

Tags: arcgis-server

When remoting into a server, then launching ArcGIS Server Manager...I can not use any of the buttons or  even view the entire web page.  I encountered this at 9.3.1 and would just launch the desktop app of AGS Manager.  At 10 there doesn't seem to be a desktop app.  I was browsing using IE (I don't know which version).

Is there a work around for this..other than not remoting in?  I have seen where some of the interface can't be scrolled to but I couldn't even click the buttons.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you make this a specific question?

Answer (score 1):

That may be a browser issue.

If you're using IE9, try clicking the Compatibility View button (the broken page in the url bar at the top of the browser) to see if that helps.

It seems fine in Chrome 12 and Firefox 5, if that helps.

Comment: I did click that..the server is running windows 7 so it was probably IE9.  I can try installing another browser and see.  Thanks.